# "Buen noche": Buen with feminine nouns?

Tags: género, saludos, concordancia-gramatical

What is the dialectal use of "buen noche"?

It doesn't sound right to me, as "noche" is feminine, but, to be sure, I've make a Google search, and I've found several occurrences, including books.

[Paraíso olvidado, de Ricardo Gil Otaiza](https://books.google.fr/books?id=M6aXl4z41oMC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=%22Buen%20noche%22&source=bl&ots=1V57VkXa1I&sig=ACfU3U0yjvW94h8lYQzkfNoRu2B3r-G7lA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_psWX4NPmAhUR4YUKHSyFAsYQ6AEwEnoECC8QBA#v=onepage&q=%22Buen%20noche%22&f=false)

> "**una buen noche** mientras mi hermana dormía y yo pensaba en nuestro azaroso destino..."

Why it isn't "buena"? Is it particularly poetical?
Could I use it like "good night!"?

Edit: Also found here:

A [book in English, here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PIG6ZHBxLugC&pg=PT276&dq=%22buen%20noche%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIqZKa-tPmAhVBQkEAHUxoDJwQ6AEIVjAE#v=onepage&q=%22buen%20noche%22&f=false))

> "Que pases **buen noche**, madre"

Source: Anales de literatura hispanoamericana - Number 12 - Page 38

> "que perdiste **una buen noche** por esto? —Sí, pero no importa"

Source: Los casí honestos - Page 95 Emilio Isaac - 1978

> La diosa Fantasía: la misma que **una buen noche** de bohemia la arrancó de aquel tablado lamentable.

Source: Bambalinas, 1919

> que me encontré al acaso en **una buen noche** en la tertulia de mi hotel de parlamentario

Source: Repertorio americano - Volume 38 - Page 299

> Juan Carlos Mondragón. de cigarrillos, refuerzos de milanesa, por una chupada en los urinarios colectivos o una botella de caña, lo ofrecido en ese pandemónium era la calma asegurada, el **pasar una buen noche** para el acompañante y la (...)

Source: El misterio Horacio Q - Page 69 Juan Carlos Mondragón

> **Buen noche**. Nos pusimos de pie y contestamos: — Buenas noches, amigos.

Source: Paiche: novela amazónica - Page 194

> Que ustedes pasen **buen noche**

Source: La Novela teatral

Comment: This doesn't make sense in any cases (dialectal, poetical, or even exception to the general rule). My vote would be for "typo" and I would compare this version with other editions.

Comment: I found several other occurrences, I'll add them.

Comment: Too many occurrences for a typo.

Comment: They seem either like typos, or grammatical errors by analogy to "buen día".

Comment: If you could find some of them in Google Books, and provide links, that would help.  I tried googling the phrase and didn't see any good hits.

Comment: I provided links and references, see in my message. It cannot be typos, because too many occurrences.

Comment: @Quidam I understand your point, but I'm going to reiterate mine as a native Spanish speaker: **it doesn't make any sense whatsoever**. I understand that I can be proven wrong by some other user explaining some obscure case/exception to the rule in a specific dialect, but until then, **"a typo"** is the most likely explanation. I see that there are too many, but they are all in  Google books? Maybe those books didn't follow a proper editorial procedure? Just imagine that all those were saying "God knight" instead of "good night" and I was asking you if that is an equivalent of "good night".

Comment: From the second link "'que tienen buen noche' the servant added". This is not good Spanish. My understanding is that the writer must be trying to convey that this character is not completely proficient in the language, although of course he is fluent. He should have said "que tenga(n) buena noche". Since I lack more context, I think this could be the case for other situations, but I can't investigate. You also might need to compare between editions to detect these typos. If this is indeed a dialectal use, not only it goes against the rules, it's absolutely unpleasant to the ear.

Comment: Yes, this one is the less good example, as it's not all written in Spanish, but for the other examples, it's found in Spanish books, so I wondered if it could be dialectal.

Comment: I agree with @Diego Typos!!

Answer (score 1):

Existe una referencia en:
"**Diccionario de Mejicanismos**" editado por la "Academia Mexicana de la Lengua" (2010)
https://www.amazon.in/Diccionario-mexicanismos-Academia-Mexicana-Lengua/dp/6070302443

aunque una primera edición (1959) es del autor **Francisco J. Santamaría**:
https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/thesaurus/pdf/16/TH_16_002_226_0.pdf

**Allí expresa:**

> Buenos escritores emplean como elegante la frase "buen hora". En
>   verdad, examinada, se ve que es una discordancia injustificada, á lo
>   menos en prosa, porque si "buen" es **apócope**
>   (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%B3cope) de bueno (no de buena),
>   concierta con los sustantivos masculinos (como buen hombre, buen
>   jinete, buen amigo, etc.)  y no con los femeninos (pues no se dice
>   buen mujer, buen casa). No puede negarse la autoridad exclusiva del
>   uso, porque en todo tiempo los buenos hablistas han dicho "buen hora",
>   "buen xxx"

---

Cuando adjetivos como malo, grande, bueno, primero o tercero se usan delante de un nombre, en español pierden una o dos letras finales y se convierten en mal, gran, buen, primer, tercer…  A esto se llama apócope y la RAE lo define como “supresión de algún sonido al final de un vocablo como en primer por primero”.

**Decimos:**

- Un buen año
- Un mal partido
- El primer paso
- El tercer puesto
- Un gran éxito

**No decimos:**

- Un bueno año
- Un malo partido
- El primero paso
- El tercero puesto
- Un grande éxito

Estos vocablos mantienen todas sus letras cuando se colocan detrás del nombre.

**Decimos:**

- Un año bueno.
- Un partido malo.
- El paso primero.
- El puesto tercero.
- Un éxito grande.

**No decimos:**

- Un año buen.
- Un partido mal.
- El paso primer.
- El puesto tercer.
- Un éxito gran.

Sin embargo, cuando agregas otro adjetivo al mismo sustantivo puedes usar indistintamente uno u otro y ambos serán correctos:

**Decimos:**

- Un buen y divertido año.
- Un bueno y divertido año.
- Un mal y aburrido partido.
- Un malo y aburrido partido.

Finalmente, ‘grande’ se convierte en ‘gran’ por delante de un sustantivo singular:

**Decimos:**

- Una gran mujer.
- Un gran primer puesto.
- Un gran paso.
- Un gran cuento.
- Una gran mentira.

**No decimos:**

- Unas gran mujeres.
- Unos gran primeros puestos.
- Unos gran pasos.
- Unos gran cuentos.
- Unas gran mentiras.

---

Decir "buen noche" no es correcto, aunque si está arraigado en la lengua, como decir "la calor", "cuanta calor" son **desvíos lingüísticos**.

Comment: A mi me suena muy extraño "Un mal y aburrido partido". Agregar el segundo adjetivo cambia todo para mi. Yo diría "Un partido malo y aburrido" o "Un malo y aburrido partido". No estoy seguro si tu respuesta es correcta o no pero me suena muy extraño y jamás lo usaría.

Comment: Lo de un mal y aburrido partido es un ejemplo. Puede tener distintos uso y costumbres.

Comment: Claro que entiendo que es un ejemplo, pero es correcto o no? Para mis oídos colombianos es un ejemplo equivocado pero no soy experto en gramática por lo que no lo puedo asegurar.

Comment: Cómo está escrito, sí, es correcto. De ahí a que se acostumbre a usarlo, hay un abismo. saludos